# Duplicating std::list with std::copy and removal with std::list::erase

Tags: c++, list, copy

In the bellow example code after assigning example list with numbers I'm trying to duplicate container with `std::copy` but problem is at runtime it says **"cannot dereference end list iterator".**

my question is how do I duplicate the list so that duplicated range is inserted to the end of the list?

to the end because I later need to be able to remove duplicated range, that is why I save the beginning of the new range to iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

void print(std::list<int>& ref)
{
    for (auto& num : ref)
    {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::list<int>::iterator iter = mylist.end();

    std::cout << "INITIAL LIST NUMBERS" << std::endl;
    print(mylist);

    // duplicate list, will cause runtime error
    iter = std::copy(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), --mylist.end());

    std::cout << "COPIED LIST IS NOW CONTAINS DUPLICATE NUMBERS" << std::endl;
    print(mylist);

    // remove previsous duplication
    mylist.erase(iter, mylist.end());

    std::cout << "AFTER REMOVAL OF COPIED LIST SHOULD BE SAME AS INITIAL LIST" << std::endl;
    print(mylist);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n). This circumvents the issue with `std::copy`, which would execute an infinite loop of insertions when fed with a `std::back_inserter(mylist)` and an always valid `mylist.end()` iterator.

```
const std::size_t n = mylist.size();
std::copy_n(mylist.cbegin(), n, std::back_inserter(mylist));
```

De-duplication then works with

```
mylist.erase(std::next(mylist.begin(), n), mylist.end());
```

Comment: That worked, do you know if it's possible to do this with std::copy?

Comment: std::copy_n, std::next() and size() definitelly a key to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (!mylist.empty()) --iter;

 std::copy_n(mylist.begin(), mylist.size(), std::back_inserter(mylist));
 if (!mylist.empty()) ++iter;
```

Unfortunately we can't use end iterator in copy(), since it might lead to an infinite loop, as new elements are added between the end and the current iterator all the time.

Comment: even though your solution is equivalent to lubgr's solution I marked his anwser because of std::next() looks more readale, thatnk you for understanding

Comment: @zebanovich note that next(begin, n) is O(n). That solution looks better but can be 30% slower (counting nodes touched)